# Data Type for EnableStatic()?

Tags: c++, api, networking, network-programming

I'm programming in **C++** a code that use **EnableStatic(),** however I constantly get error for using inadequate **data type**...  I tried fix it by myself and in return that shows up:

Error: ' no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "[a data type]" exists'

---

Maybe a really noobish ;-; question but real pain in the back; what **data type** should I use then?

---

Additional Info

**the website of the method**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Web of the function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383(v=vs.85).aspx

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>

    int main(){
std::string ipaddr = "155.34.22.0";
     std::string subnet = "255.255.255.0";

     uint32_t EnableStatic (ipaddr, subnet);

     system("pause");
        }
```

**Error Description:**

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "uint32_t" exists

Comment: Please edit your question, and include a [mcve].

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik edited and here you have the code ;)

Comment: This looks to me like the function expects an IP address and netmask to be given as raw 32 bit ints, instead of a string. See, the problem here is that the documentation you linked to is not really C++. What Microsoft calls C++ is not what the rest of the world calls C++. As such, you're being done a disservice by learning stuff that you think is C++, but which is not. Despite the impression given by the linked documentation, based on the error message the parameter is not a string. Try using inet_addr() to convert a C-style string to an `inet_addr_t`, an integer network address.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik This solved partially the problem because error doesn't show up. However I get error because VS expects ')' instead of ','...I think the problem is because I haven't call the function from the class; I found a rather complicated example for the function  : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/387500/Cplusplus-WMI-EnableStatic-with-multiple-IPs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sign*

So, I've discovered it wasn't entirely 'bout the data type but matter is it's a WMI method. It's possible to call it in C++ by using COM object and then call the method from the class, all of it indirectly.

There is an example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390421(v=vs.85).aspx

---

Thanks to for helping

@Sam Varshavchik